# How to connect the intuitions to the math of adaptive processes?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, intuition, measure-theory

## Formal Definition

Wikipedia gives the following definition of a process adapted to a filtration:

> - Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space;
> - $I$ be an index set with total order $\leq$ (often, $I$ is $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N_0}$, or $[0, T]$, or $[0, +\infty)$);
> - $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_i)_{i \in I}$ be a filtration of the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$'
> - $(S, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space, the *state space*;
> - $X : I \times \Omega \mapsto S$ be a stochastic process.
>   The process $X$ is said to be **adapted to the filtration** $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i \in I}$ if the random variable $X_i : \Omega \mapsto S$ is a $(\mathcal{F}_i, \Sigma)$-measurable function for each $i \in I$.

## Informal Definitions

Wikipedia gives there informal definitions, or intuitions, of what adaptive processes are like.

### One

> [A]n adapted process (also referred to as a non-anticipating or non-anticipative process) is one that cannot "see into the future".

### Two

> An informal interpretation is that $X$ is adapted if and only if, for every realisation and every $n$, $X_n$ is known at time $n$.

## Question

When I read the formal definition I get the impression that the filtrations are of key importance in providing some kind of constraint on what we can know. Filtrations have a defining property that $\mathcal{F}_k \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\ell}$ whenever $k \leq \ell$. My speculation is the filtrations are imposing that if time $a$, then the function $X_{a+n}$ for $n>0$ is not measurable. So we're not saying that $X_a$ is independent of $X_{a+n}$, but rather that it won't measurable until the time is $\geq a+n$. At least, that is my attempt to understand it anyway.

How does the formal definition relate to the informal definitions (or intuitions, if you like)?

Comment: The binomial options pricing model I illustrate at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/123754/919 provides a nice example of this that requires only a minimal amount of measure theory to understand.

Comment: One can say that the filtration at time $t$ is the set of events observed up to time $t$: it is possible to say at time $t$ whether such an event has been realized.